Non pregnant female stealing kittens from a mother
I have two female cats that were dumped on our property,who have both had kittens. My mother has several cats and lives with me. She has four females unfixed two which haven't had litters and aren't in heat. All four keep stealing the babies from the new mothers and it seems to have become a competition for who will read them,only the mothers have milk. What should I do?
